# Where can I find a jpa 2.1 osgi bundle

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, osgi

We would like to use the converter functionality of jpa 2.1, as described on http://hantsy.blogspot.nl/2013/12/jpa-21-attribute-converter.html. As we are developing an osgi based product, a 'simple jpa 2.1 jar' isn't sufficient for our purposes, we need an osgi bundle. On the Spring EBR (http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.persistence) I only find older versions of JPA. Hence my question: where can I find a jpa 2.1 osgi bundle?

Comment: I don't agree. I got two helpful answers to my question. By putting such questions on hold you prevent people like me from getting very sensible answers like the one below.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the new aries jpa release:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/aries-dev/201407.mbox/%3C53C6D542.4050701%40nanthrax.net%3E

It is already on maven central and allows to work with jpa 2.1 providers like hibernate 4.3.x.